# Laravel Excel Import variable cell data into db and show in blade table

Tags: laravel

I'm in a bit of a pickle,

I'm working on a way to upload xlsx files which contain variable data.

The first row is are the names of questions where the first 2 records (A, B) are default data and from C to $variable are labeled as v001, v002, v003_1, v003_1_open(it's variable, see below):

BatchNo | Time_Stamp | v000_1 | v001 | v002 | v002_1 | v002_1_open | v003

The second row consists of just input(in relation to the heading => BatchNo on row 1 has 123456 as input on row 2, 67891 on row 3 and so on.

Now I'm trying to figure out if I can somehow save this dataset into a table which allow me to then extract it and show it on a page in a html table. I'm struggling to find a way to store the variable data, because it's never fixed and could be 5 cells, 10 cells or even 20.
[Example of an excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnf62.jpg)

Comment: If you import the sheet, convert each row to an array, and then print_r each row, do the rows with blank entries (say Q4 and R4 in your example) have null values in the array for those entries? So does row 4 return as BatchNo, Timestamp, null, null, 10, 10, 10 (etc..) or BatchNo, Timestamp, 10, 10, 10, (etc...)?

Comment: The first row will always consist of data, the first 2 cells will always be BatchNo and Time_Stamp. In the first row cells 3 to ..(depending on the imported excel) will always be variable(v001...v020, whichs represent question+number of question). The second row will either return a value or returns NULL. I'm looking for a way to import it all and save it somewhere to access it and display on a page.